# Is there an incomplete normed space which is Asplund?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

Can there exist an incomplete normed space which is Asplund?

Answer (score 2):

The property of being an Asplund space is normally *defined for Banach spaces only*. If you try to apply the same definition without requiring completeness, the question arises: [which of many definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asplund_space) to use? These are known to be equivalent for Banach spaces.

Most of the definitions refer to the dual space (i.e., $X$ is Asplund iff $X^*$ has the Radon–Nikodým property; or if every separable subspace of $X$ has separable dual). If $X$ is a dense subspace of a Banach space $Y$ (with the same norm), then $X^*=Y^*$, and similarly for subspaces. So, $Y$ being Asplund implies $X$ being Asplund, by these definitions.

In particular, the space of sequences that are eventually zero, equipped with the $\ell^2$ norm, would be an incomplete Asplund space according to the above.

Comment: Thanks...I guess the property that if X is a Banachs space then its dense subspaces are all Asplund spaces augurs well with the space I was looking for. I was looking at $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcup L^{\infty)(\Omega)$.

Comment: But isn't it true that your result holds only when Y is separable?

Comment: @Alexander Um, you were looking at $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcup L^{\infty}(\Omega)$? But $L^\infty$ is certainly not Asplund. It contains an isometric copy of $\ell^1$, whose dual is not separable.

Comment: Yes you are right...sorry what I meant was $\bigcap$.  What I realise is that the space $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ w.r.t. the norm of $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: But isn't your result true only if you consider a separable, Banach space?...moreover $Y^{*}=X^{*}$ only if $X$ is dense in $Y$.

Comment: Can someone please reply to my query just above?.